# how do we copy file from hadoop to abfs remotely

Tags: azure, hadoop

how do we copy files from Hadoop to abfs (azure blob file system)
I want to copy from Hadoop fs to abfs file system but it throws an error
this is the command I ran

hdfs dfs -ls abfs://....

```
ls: No FileSystem for scheme "abfs"

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem not found
```

any idea how this can be done ?

Answer (score 0):

In the `core-site.xml` you need to add a config property for `fs.abfs.impl` with value `org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem`, and then add any other related authentication configurations it may need.

More details on installation/configuration here - https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-azure/abfs.html

Comment: nope.. I tried this and does NOT work.. I still get the same error

Comment: Please edit your question to include what exactly you've changed.

Comment: just the error message I have updated.

Comment: Does your installation have `hadoop-azure` JAR on the classpath? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-azure

Answer (score 0):

the abfs binding is already in core-default.xml for any release with the abfs client present. however, the hadoop-azure jar and dependency is not in the hadoop common/lib dir where it is needed (it is in HDI, CDH, but not the apache one)

you can tell the hadoop script to pick it and its dependencies up by setting the `HADOOP_OPTIONAL_TOOLS` env var; you can do this in `~/.hadoop-env`; just try on your command line first

```bash
export HADOOP_OPTIONAL_TOOLS="hadoop-azure,hadoop-aws"
```

after doing that, download the latest cloudstore jar and use its storediag command to attempt to connect to an abfs URL; it's the place to start debugging classpath and config issues

https://github.com/steveloughran/cloudstore

Comment: hdfs dfs -ls abfs://testdatalake@testdatasaqaeastus2.dfs.core.windows.net
ls: No FileSystem for scheme: abfs

 echo $HADOOP_OPTIONAL_TOOLS
/path/hadoop-aws-3.3.4.jar,/path/hadoop-azure-3.3.4.jar

Comment: I still get same error

Comment: the Hadoop cluster is running in hdinsight in azure and I want to connect locally.

Comment: HADOOP_OPTIONAL_TOOLS must refer to module, not path. otherwise, grab cloudstore.jar from https://github.com/steveloughran/cloudstore and use its storediag command to identify what is missing/incorrectly configured